# How to add a custom button in echart toolbox such that clicking on it should add a new series in linechart?

Tags: javascript, typescript, apache-echarts

I want a drop down in the echart toolbox such that I can select series to be shown. In the example, the drop-down should contain `[Email, Union Ads, Video Ads, Direct, Search Engine]` and the user should be able to select one or more. How can I achieve this?

[Echart example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-stack)

Note: My usecase is to show the dropdown with the list and on selection it will get the data from DB via sql.